# I am not able to store an element of an array into a register using x86 assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

The following is my code in assembly:

```
    mov esi, MemberLvl
    mov edi, OfficerLst

    mov al, [esi]
    mov test1, al
    mov ah, [edi]
    mov test2, ah
```

In the C++ main program, I have declared a list of type long called *MemberLvl* and *OfficerLst*, and two long types - *test1* and *test2*.

Whenever I try to run my code, it keeps saying there is an operand size conflict with `mov test1, al` and `mov test2, ah`.

My thinking is that each array is stored in `esi` and `edi`. I then store the first element into `al` or `ah` by getting their first memory address. Because each long is 8 bytes and the `al` or `ah` register is 8 bytes, I'm thinking it will be able to store this into *test1* and *test2* (which are both declared a long, 8 bytes), but it isn't. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al` and `ah` are **8-bit** values (1 byte). `test1` and `test2` are "long" according to you, which is either 32 bit (4 bytes) or 64 bit (8 bytes), depending on your compiler / system.

If you want to store the values in the respective variables, you can use `movzx` (if unsigned) or `movsx` (if signed).

---

Also, note that if `MemberLvl` is a `long`, then moving it to `esi`, then doing `[esi]` is likely undefined behaviour, unless `MemberLvl` happened to contain a valid pointer address. If `MemberLvl` is a `long *`, then it's probably fine, but then `[esi]` is a 32 bit or 64 bit value, and thus you shouldn't use `al` or `ah` at all.

Comment: Oh thanks! That makes more sense, so now my code is using type chars. My other problem now is that I am storing the first element into al, however, when I store al into test1, it shows a random symbol instead of the first element in the array. Do you know why this could be happening? Thanks.

Comment: @Jen, If it's showing "random chars", then I think you are storing non-displayable character codes into the array. I would recommend making a new question, with fuller details (i.e. surrounding code which is populating values, how you're printing, etc.).